Ones again about multiple types in typescript. How?
How to make var of multiple types
Example
interface Iroot {
    a:any;

}


interface IType1 
{
    first:any;
}
interface IType2
{
    second:any
}

interface Iq {
    variable : IType1 | IType2;
}

var a: Iq;


how make variable of Iq type than it be IType1 or IType2
In my case TS say - Property 'first' does not exist on type 'IType1 | IType2'
I need that work only a.first =1 or a.second =2

• What does this title mean? What is "ones again about"? Maybe... "once again"?  But why that? Is this a question in a series of questions? Please [edit] to make the title as clear and to the point as possible. Right now all I understand is "multiple types" and even that isn't clearly about "or", which seems to be the point. • This is not a [mre]. You're not using IRoot at all, and the code you've presented doesn't have the error you're mentioning. Please [edit] the code so it demonstrates your issue clearly and effectively. • Possible duplicate

Your code does exactly that, variable is either of type IType1 or of type IType2. Which one, is (also for the compiler) impossible to say without further checks. Ie if you then do foo.variable.first the compiler can't be sure, that this first exists thus it throws an error. If you want to be able to do this, you need something like a Type Predicate Once you determined whether variable is of type IType1 or IType2  only variable.first or variable.second will work.

yes. provided duplicate is simiar. I think i understand! I MUST SET or GET values to FIRST and SECOND only via predicates? in this case compiler will know accurate type?

You need to make sure that you assign the property that exists. You wrote that the type may be IType1 or IType2, so first may not exists. You can write just a simple condition:
if ('first' in a.variable) {
  a.variable.first = 1;
)

or write a guard:
const isType1 = (variable: IType1 | IType2): variable is IType1 => 'first' in variable;

if (isType1(a.variable)) {
  a.variable.first = 1;
}

